# Generic conversion

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Basically I'm doing is converting from Exception to GenericFaultException class (The below code snippet uses C# as a language.

See the below details

```
FaultException<T>:FaultException(FaultException derived from exception)

FaultException:Exception
```

I have created a faultExceptionObject using the below line of code

```
public class ValidationFault: IValidationFault
{
}

FaultException<ValidationFault> faultExceptionObject=new FaultException<ValidationFault>(new ValidationFault())
```

I have a Error handling layer which do not have any idea about ValidationFault class,only it knows IValidationFault.

```
public Exception HandleException(Exception exception, Guid handlingInstanceId)
{    
  FaultException<IValidationFault> genericFaultException = exception as FaultException<IValidationFault>;
   //********genericFaultException is always NULL**********************
   IValidationFault fault = genericFaultException.Detail as IValidationFault;
 }
```

For some reason the line:

```
FaultException<IValidationFault> genericFaultException = exception as FaultException<IValidationFault>;
```

results in genericFaultException **always equal to null**, but from the QuickWatch I see Exception is of type `FaultException<ValidationFault>`. How should I convert from `Exception` to `FaultException<IValidationFault>`?

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like C#, but I shouldn't have to guess. Please add an appropriate language tag.

Comment: It's definitely about generics.

Comment: @Tejas: yes, now it actually is. But please read the V1 ;)

Comment: I guess I can see where you got that from :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `exception as FaultException<IValidationFault>` is null is because a `FaultException<ValidationFault>` is *not* a `FaultException<IValidationFault>`.

For this operation to work as you want, `FaultException<T>` must be written so that `T` is covariant.  But you cannot do that in c# for classes.  You have to use an interface.  Here is an example that should work:

```
public interface IFaultException<out T>
{
    T Detail { get; }
}

public class FaultException<T> : Exception, IFaultException<T>
{
    private T _detail;
    public T Detail { get { return _detail; } }
    public FaultException(T detail, string message, Exception innerException)
    : base(message, innerException)
    {
       _detail = detail;
    }
}
```

With this class and interface, down in your error handling code you should be able to do:

```
IFaultException<IValidationFault> genericFaultException =
    exception as IFaultException<IValidationFault>;
```

This is because your exception (which you know is really a `FaultException<ValidationFault>`) implements `IFaultException<ValidationFault>`.  Since `IFaultException<T>` is covariant for `T`, this means any `IFaultException<ValidationFault>` can also be used as `IFaultException<IValidationFault>`.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, this is what i was expecting.

Comment: Cool.  Don't forget to accept the answer if this indeed answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the normal way is to create a new instance of Exception and set its properties (copying from FaultException), or using a constructor within Exception that takes a FaultException as argument, but this would be a bit strange because a base class should not have knowledge about its subclass(es).